# AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'output'

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, tf.keras, keras-layer

I use to get a Heatmap of my image classification model to learn how my model makes decisions to adjust the model. But unfortunately i get an error and I dont know how to fix it correctly.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

# Display
from IPython.display import Image, display
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
from keras.preprocessing import image
import numpy as np
import os
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, load_img
from tensorflow.keras import models
from timeit import default_timer as timer
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
from keras.models import load_model

model_builder = keras.applications.xception.Xception
img_size = (299, 299)
preprocess_input = keras.applications.xception.preprocess_input
decode_predictions = keras.applications.xception.decode_predictions

img_path = "box.jpg"

def make_gradcam_heatmap(
    img_array, model, last_conv_layer_name, classifier_layer_names
):
    # First, we create a model that maps the input image to the activations
    # of the last conv layer
    last_conv_layer = layer_output = model.get_layer('vgg16').get_layer(last_conv_layer_name).output
    last_conv_layer_model = keras.Model(model.inputs, last_conv_layer.output)

# Prepare image
img_array = preprocess_input(get_img_array(img_path, size=img_size))

# Make model
model = models.load_model("Box_Model_Augmented(15.11).h5")

last_conv_layer_name = "block5_conv3"
classifier_layer_names = ["global_max_pooling2d", "predictions"]

# Generate class activation heatmap
heatmap = make_gradcam_heatmap(
    img_array, model, last_conv_layer_name, classifier_layer_names
)
```

[image]

Comment: You are using .output two times on the same variable, only once is necessary.

Comment: Which tensorflow and keras version are you using? Please try again by importing keras libraries using prefix `tensorflow.keras` like -  `from tensorflow.keras.utils import load_img`, `from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model`. Also, let us know how you have defined `get_img_array()` to replicate the code error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are encountering an error related to importing Keras from TensorFlow. The issue might be due to the way Keras is being imported. Instead of using from keras, you should use from tensorflow.keras to import Keras from TensorFlow.

Here's how you can modify your code:

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
```